# I'm trying to define a function in Google Colab but im getting this error: "name 'model_norm' is not defined"

Tags: python, dataset, google-colaboratory, training-data

history_norm = model_norm.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=400, batch_size=10,
verbose=0, validation_data=(X_test_norm, y_test_norm))

please help me to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that your model_norm is not initialized or defined correctly prior to calling the model fit function and example for model fit could be written as follows

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

model_norm = Sequential()
model_norm.add(Dense(64, input_dim=10, activation='relu'))
model_norm.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model_norm.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

history_norm = model_norm.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=400, batch_size=10, verbose=0, validation_data=(X_test_norm, y_test_norm))
```

Comment: I've tried it, but the code you provided is still an error

Comment: ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 1) vs (None, 6)).

Comment: you will need to use your data and update the code accordingly you can't just run the code with no data